# Taxonomy Sidebar view with Nodes

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a sidebar for my taxonomy and node pages.

I've got it as

- Show (View Setup): Taxonomy Terms
- Unformatted List
- Show: Fields
- Relationship: Taxonomy term: Representative node

Fields:

- Taxonomy term: Name
- (Representative node) Content: Title

This works pretty well, each row starts with the taxonomy term name as a link and is followed by a node from that term. The trouble is, it'll only show the first node. How do I get it to display all nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Representative node relationship will show you a single representative node for your term, so that's not what you need in this case. Instead, try this:

**Relationship**: *Taxonomy term: Content with term*

Your results will now look like this:

Term A

Node 1

Term A

Node 2

Term B

Node 3 etc

Assuming this is not what you want, you can next add some grouping like this:

Under **Format: settings** set **Grouping field Nr. 1** to *Taxonomy term: Name*.
Finally, in Fields, set the **Taxonomy term: Name** field to *Exclude from display*. Now you should have a list of node titles grouped by taxonomy term.